# Automatically kill blocking and report result

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I automatically find and kill long term blocking (suppose 1 hour)queries  on a particular database on particular server instances and also report result to see the killed block queries.

Comment: [sp_whoIsActive](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2010/09/sql-server-dba-scripts-how-to-find-slow-sql-server-queries/amp/) is nice but this is really something many people use a DB monitoring tool for

Answer (score 0):

you can see all the server transactions with

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_exec_requests
```

This one shows only queries and the processing time [here](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/See%20what%20queries%20are%20currently%20running.aspx)

```
SELECT      r.start_time [Start Time],session_ID [SPID],
        DB_NAME(database_id) [Database],
        SUBSTRING(t.text,(r.statement_start_offset/2)+1,
        CASE WHEN statement_end_offset=-1 OR statement_end_offset=0 
        THEN (DATALENGTH(t.Text)-r.statement_start_offset/2)+1 
        ELSE (r.statement_end_offset-r.statement_start_offset)/2+1
        END) [Executing SQL], 
        Status,command,wait_type,wait_time,wait_resource, 
        last_wait_type
FROM        sys.dm_exec_requests r
OUTER APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) t
WHERE       session_id != @@SPID -- don't show this query
AND         session_id > 50 -- don't show system queries
ORDER BY    r.start_time
```

and if you want to kill a blocking process:

```
KILL [session_id]
```

Comment: I was looking for creating sql job which find blocking and kill it and send out an email with the report.

Comment: I still think this is what you need. The query gives you running time, you may write a program to run the query and to kill those that are taking longer than your threshold.